# Convert jupyter notebook to pdf: Error encounters when install pandoc

Tags: python, html, jupyter, nbconvert

I was trying to convert  .ipynb to a pdf.
I'm on Windows and use Jupyter via IE browser.

I'm following the link http://pandoc.org/installing.html to install Pandoc.
Here's what I have done: Any suggestions?

- Install MikTex: http://miktex.org/download
- Install pandoc

  - Install stack:
  - -got to cmd from pandoc folder, run stack setup
  - -stack init
  - -stack install---->ERRORS!!

  [image]

Comment: `Please check that pandoc is installed: http://pandoc.org/installing.html` did you actually do that? `pandoc` is not a python package. You cannot install it via pip. Consider following the advice given in this link.

Comment: @cel Thanks..Please see my updates

Comment: It looks like you're trying to install pandoc from source. I've done that once, but it spent about 45 minutes compiling stuff. I'd definitely recommend using the [binary installer](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/download/1.17.2/pandoc-1.17.2-windows.msi) unless you know you need to compile it from source.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like an alternative to it instead of using nbconvert what you can do is :

1. Download your ipynb file as HTML from File option.
2. Right-click and select print or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
3. Save as PDF

Easy.